# get list data from firebase, or how to structure the data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, mvvm

How can I get my list data from a json object like this:

```
users: {
  uid: {
    name: "user1",
    items: {
      itemID1: {
        name: "item1"
      },
      itemID2: {
       name: "item2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I get this list of Items and use it with an MVVM structure. 
I tried to do the same thing that this article is doing with friends. But I am using firebase to load data.

https://medium.com/@stasost/ios-how-to-build-a-table-view-with-multiple-cell-types-2df91a206429

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want if you want to display different cells for different users you ned String enum with cell registration and then have switch for them. I guess you don't want answer how to parse JSON.

For the article you need to fill the data model which looks like this

```
class Profile {
   var fullName: String?
   var pictureUrl: String?
   var email: String?
   var about: String?
   var friends = [Friend]()
   var profileAttributes = [Attribute]()
}
class Friend {
   var name: String?
   var pictureUrl: String?
}
class Attribute {
   var key: String?
   var value: String?
}
```

so you need data like this

```
users: {
  uid: {
    fullName: "user1",
    pictureUrl: "svff",
    email: "dfdf@gmail.com",
    about: "Hello, world!",
    friends: {
      0: {
        name: "Jon",
        pictureUrl : "dfbdvsd"
      },
      1: {
        name: "Tyrion",
        pictureUrl : "dfbdvsd"
      }
    },
    attributes: {
      0: {
        key: "key1",
        value : "value1"
      },
      1: {
        key: "key2",
        value : "value2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```